# images in discussion forum?

Tags: discussion

I am unable to see the image that appear inside a question

[Using scenes and render layers to composite an object isolated on white background with shadow](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3002/using-scenes-and-render-layers-to-composite-an-object-isolated-on-white-backgrou)

[image]

Comment: Are you on a mobile device?  Sometimes images appear broken for me when I am on the mobile site on my phone.  They do have a mobile app though where I can see images fine, it has other problems though.